# How to load and use environment-related values in config phase

Tags: json, angularjs

I would like to deploy my web application to several environments. Using Continuous Integration I can run a task to generate a config.json for a particular environment. This file will contain, among others, the particular URLs to use for it.

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://www.myapp.es/",
  "baseApiUrl": "http://api.myapp.es/",
  "baseAuthUrl": "http://api.myapp.es/auth/"
}
```

The issue comes up when I try to set my different services through providers in the config phase. Of course, services are not available yet in the phase so I cannot use *$http* to load that json file and set my providers correctly.

Basically I would like to do something like:

```
  function config($authProvider) {
    $authProvider.baseUrl = config.baseAuthUrl;
  }
```

Is there a way to load those values on runtime from a file? The only thing I can think about is having that mentioned task altering this file straight away. However I have several modules and therefore, that would have to do in all of them which doesn´t seem right.

Comment: We handle it by altering the entry point in our browserify process, thus allowing us to require our config file and modify it before requiring the production entry point when building for development.

Comment: We are not using Browserify... but I understand your point. I cannot find any other solution, I will give this a go. Thanks!

Comment: hmm. where does the json file come from? if it's coming from the remote endpoint, it is relatively useless because you don't know what the remote endpoint is without the json file. It'l have to be local. If it's local, it's relatively easy to just ajax it in and use it. I would simplify this by making it a .js file and including it using a script tag, thus ensuring it is available before angular boots up.

Comment: The file is generated by the CI engine. So I have it available from the very beginning but I cannot load it using ajax since I need some of values in it to set my providers up and $http is not available then. I might go with generating angular constants in a separate file for my core module rather than the previous json.

Comment: having the ci engine generate a .js file instead that populates an object that is a property of `window` might be the easiest solution. Otherwise you'll have to somehow delay the angular boot process until after you've requested the json file using xhr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the solution was generating an angular constants file using templating (gulp-template) through a gulp task. At the end, I am using a yaml file instead a json one (which is the one generated my CI engine with the proper values for the environment I want to deploy to).

Basically:

*config.yml*

```
  baseUrl: 'http://www.myapp.es/'
  baseApiUrl: 'http://api.myapp.es/'
  auth:
    url: 'auth/'
```

*config.module.constants.template*

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.config')
    .constant('env_variables', {
      baseUrl: '<%=baseUrl%>',
      baseApiUrl: '<%=baseApiUrl%>',
      authUrl: '<%=auth.url%>'
    });

}());
```

*gulpfile.js*

```
gulp.task('splicing', function(done) {
  var yml = path.join(conf.paths.src, '../config/config.yml');
  var json = yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync(yml, 'utf8'));
  var template = path.join(conf.paths.src, '../config/config.module.constants.template');
  var targetFile = path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/config');

  return gulp.src(template)
    .pipe($.template(json))
    .pipe($.rename("config.module.constants.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(targetFile), done);
});
```

Then you just inject it in the config phase you need:

```
 function config($authProvider, env_variables) {
    $authProvider.baseUrl = env_variables.baseApiUrl + env_variables.authUrl;
  }
```

One more benefit about using gulp for this need is that you can integrate the generation of these constants with your build, serve or watch tasks and literally, forget about doing any change from now on. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can create constants in the config of your main module:

1. Add $provide as a dependency in your config method
2. use the provider method to add all constants like this

   $provide.provider('BASE_API_URL', {
                   $get: function () {
                        return 'https://myexample.net/api/';
                   }
               });
3. You can use BASE_API_URL as a dependency in your services.

I hope this helps

Optionally you can set the url depending of your environment:

```
$provide.provider('BASE_API_URL', {
                $get: function () {
                    if(window.location.hostname.toLowerCase() == 'myapp.myexample.net')
                    {
                        return 'https://myexample.net/api/' //pre-production

                    }else
                    {

                        return 'http://localhost:61132/'; //local

                    }
                }
            });
```

Regards!

Comment: Thanks for your idea. Unfortunately, I still have the same issue, I need to load those URLs from a json file and be able to use them in config phase. Also, I cannot inspect window.location since I might have even five different environments (ci, qa, staging, production...).

Comment: And if you have a core module to do that, in this module you maybe have a ConfigService to get the json file and set any values in this service, you should load this core modle first and then the other modules use as a dependency, Use the ConfigService.getXConfigVariable() in your services or In your config method of any module you shuld set like $authProvider.baseUrl = ConfigService.getBaseAuthUrl();

Other option is using var host = window.location.hostname.toLowerCase(); and then using a switch statement inested of if, but as you said, you have 5 environments.

Comment: I have already another module loading the config.json and exposing it through a ConfigService. But how do I manage to have an instance of it ready to use? Services and factories are available after config phase and is in that phase when I need this service. Sorry, maybe I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: You are right, i will try test this scenery because actually i have this definition in my core module using the if like my first example but i have only 3 environments. I'm not sure if the services defined in the config of the core module are available in the config of the other modules, but i believe that it should be available because my current config in core module define constants like in my example and then i use in the other modules.

Comment: Constants from a module are available for another module config phase, services and factories are not, I just tried it. Anyway, what I am going to do is having my CI engine generating a angular constants file which is available straight away rather than a json I need to load using http. I have tested and it works fine. At the end, it is quite similar to what your propose at the beginning with a couple of tweaks. I will post here the final code. Thanks mate.

Comment: Your Welcome. For replace, somthing like this?: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace . I don't know if you have $http call in the config fase , get values and declare constans in the core Module with this values ?

Regards

Comment: Exactly that gulp task! I can grab my json in gulp when generating my dist code and using templating through this gulp-replace generate my core constants. This is the one :)

Comment: Hi, I've already done the changes. Hope the code is clear and you can use it. Thanks for your help!